# WKWebView problems in iOS 9

Tags: swift2, ios9, wkwebview

I'm having trouble with WKWebView in XCode 7 using the iOS 9 sdk. For some reason, half of the websites I try to load come up blank (for example mobile Facebook).

WKWebView worked perfectly when I built my app on iOS 8. I haven't changed any of the code for loading webpages (I used loadrequest with a nsurl), and I know that the webviews are active because some links do load.

Is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be related to a new feature called ATS (App Transport Security), which was introduced in iOS 9.

Please see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

> All connections using the NSURLConnection, CFURL, or NSURLSession APIs
>   use App Transport Security default behavior in apps built for iOS 9.0
>   or later, and OS X 10.11 or later. Connections that do not follow the
>   requirements will fail.

It is possible to add exceptions or to allow any non-secured connections. For example, you can add this to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you!

Comment: After this change, mine worked for like one time, then later builds quit working again ...